# Change website background from gif to color on click

Tags: javascript, css, html

I know there are plenty of questions about changing background color, but they don't seem to work with my site, where I have a gif as the initial background.

Start of my `html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> <!-- to load my bloody euro sign-->
        <title>
            CV - Rogier
        </title>
        <style>
            body{ background: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/ko7twHhomhk8E/giphy.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            background-size: cover;
            }
```

So how can I change the background to a solid color by pressing a button?
(Either by using a black picture link or `color:black` , but I prefer the latter)

I was thinking about something like this, but I have no clue how to call the background property:

```
<button style="font-size: 200%;color: white" onclick="document.body.style.background:url(https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/joke-battles/images/5/5a/Black.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20161223050425) = 'black';">Click here if the page lags</button>
```

Comment: I don't see any of the code you tried - did you miss that?

Comment: Please include the code you've already tried.

Comment: background-opacity isn't a css property.

Comment: Added, and I didn't mean to leave opacity in, that was an old test line.

Comment: `document.body.style.background = 'red';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the background, you must simply remove the background image assuming that you have previously set the background color. While you can use JQuery to do this, it's kind of overkill.

Also, don't use inline HTML event attributes (`onclick`, `onmouseover`, etc.) as they:

1. Create "spaghetti code" that is difficult to read and debug.
2. Lead to duplication of code.
3. Don't scale well
4. Don't follow the **[separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)** development methodology.
5. Create anonymous global wrapper functions around your attribute values that alter the `this` binding in your callback functions.
6. Don't follow the **[W3C Event Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#introduction-to-dom-events)**.

Instead, do all your work in JavaScript and use **[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** to set up event handlers.

Similarly, try to avoid inline CSS styles when you can.

Here's the code:

```js
// Get references to the DOM elements you'll work with
var bdy = document.body;
var btn = document.getElementById("btnChange");

// Set up the button to have a click event handler:
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  /* Just remove the image and the page will revert to the previously set color */
  bdy.style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
});
```

```css
body{
  background: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/ko7twHhomhk8E/giphy.gif) no-repeat center center fixed #000; 
  background-size: cover;
}

#btnChange {
  font-size: 200%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnChange">Click here if the page lags</button>
```

Comment: Nice solution. Just missing a space between the `button` opening tag and the `id`.

Comment: @freginold Thanks. Updated.

Comment: not sure if it's an IE 11 issue (my browser) but when I run the snippet it has a black background on load.

Comment: @freginold You will see a black background by default until the image has finished downloading to the client. IE (all versions) is slower to load pages than other browsers.

Comment: I'll take your word for it -- I don't have access to any other browsers to test it on. Leaving it for a couple of minutes in IE11 it remains with the black background.

Comment: @freginold It could be a variety of things. It's possible that you have the display of images turned off in your settings. It's also possible that you have not placed the JavaScript into the web page at the correct location (it should be in a `<script>` tag that is placed just before the closing of the `body` (`</body>`). But the code is very simple and standard. There is nothing in my solution that wouldn't work in IE going back to IE 9.  As you can see, it works here in the Stack Overflow environment.

Comment: That's what I mean... your snippet wouldn't load the image for me in IE11. It's not an image issue in general -- the image in my snippet (and other snippets for other pages) loads fine.  I'll play around with it later... just had a chance to try it in Chrome and it works as intended.

Comment: Nevermind, got it, it was a security issue with that link.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. A small problem is that we haven't been taught javascript jet, but I think my limited coding knowledge should be enough to understand and reproduce this.

Comment: @RnRoger The JavaScript used in Scott's answer is very simple. Basically all you are doing is targeting the button and adding a "listener" to it so that when the button is clicked, it calls the function which in turn changes the background from the image to the solid color.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track.  Your `onclick` attribute needs to be fixed up a little bit.  Here's a working example:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Male_mallard_duck_2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> <!-- to load my bloody euro sign-->
        <title>
            CV - Rogier
        </title>
</head>

<body>
    <button style="font-size: 200%;color: white" onclick="document.body.style.background = 'black';">Click here if the page lags</button>
</body>
```

As pointed out by @ScottMarcus, you should avoid using inline event handlers (like `onclick`).  A cleaner and more manageable way to do that would be to add the event handler through JavaScript, like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.body.style.background = 'black';
});
```

Comment: Inline HTML event handlers should always be avoided.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Agree -- just going with what the OP already had. I'll edit my answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

> here is jquery code for change background

```
$('button').click(function()
   {

    $('body').css("background","url(/myimage.jpg) #000");

   });
```